# iScroll doesn't work in template loaded with jquery

Tags: android, ios, cordova, iscroll

In the index.html of a phonegap project I have configured iScroll (https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll).

If I put the html code with the iScroll classes needed directly in the file index.html, everything works, but if I load the html code with jquery it doesn't work.

I load the template in this way:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "file.html",
                cache: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    var source = data;
                    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
                    $( '#div' ).html(template({ test: "test" }));
                }
            });
```

I also tried to load all iScroll script in the template but nothing.

Thanks

Comment: seems like iScroll haven't been initializated or it's container element have not been rendered yet, try to console.log your IScroll variable and your container

Comment: Just a side note: Use can actually get native scroll with css. Add **-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;** to your div, and it will act like **overflow: auto;** in normal browser.

Comment: after get content dynamic by jQuery is finish, you must refresh iScroll